# TYPO3 scheduler is not called although the cron job is running

Tags: cron, typo3, scheduler, typo3-8.x

We have one installation where the scheduler is not working any more since May 18th.

Only now we noticed it and have no clue what has changed in May when the scheduler stopped working.

The crontab entry has not changed and is:

```
* * * * * wwwrun export TYPO3_CONTEXT="Production";/usr/bin/php /srv/www/htdocs/DOMAIN.TLD/web/typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run
```

But the BE module does not register any call and states:
`The Scheduler was last started (automatically) on 18-05-20 at 12:54 and ended on 18-05-20 at 12:54.`

In the TYPO3 log there are entries about the successful start in May, but no more since then. Especially no error messages.

Since I started a task manually in the BE module it states:
`The Scheduler was last started (manually) on 07-12-20 at 11:41 and ended on 07-12-20 at 11:45.`

What can we do to get more information on command line or any log file what happens  with the command started from cron or CLI?

Comment: Are there any errors if you're firing the command on CLI?

Comment: nothing. it just returns to the command prompt

Comment: Hmm, nothing would also be the answer if everything went right... The binary is executable? I.e. without the "scheduler:run" do you get an output on the CLI?